# Pyspark: Join 2 dataframes with different number of rows by duplication

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Good day everyone,

Suppose I want to join the following two dataframes so that the one row of df2 gets duplicated in the join for every row in df1 which has the same id:

```
df1 = sc.parallelize(Array((0, 1.5, 8.4, 9.1),
                           (0, 5.9, 1.3, 3.3),
                           (0, 3.2, 7.9, 4.2),
                           (0, 6.9, 2.2, 1.2)))
                           .toDF("id", "col1", "col2", "col3")

df2 = sc.parallelize(Array((0, 2.1, 3.4, 4.2)))
                           .toDF("id", "col4", "col5", "col6")
```

The desired result would look as follows:

```
df_joined.show() 

+---+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+
| id| col1|col2 |col3 |col4|col5 |col6 |
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+
|  0|  1.5|  8.4|  9.1| 2.1|  3.4|  4.2|
|  0|  5.9|  1.3|  3.3| 2.1|  3.4|  4.2|
|  0|  3.2|  7.9|  4.2| 2.1|  3.4|  4.2|
|  0|  6.9|  2.2|  1.2| 2.1|  3.4|  4.2|
+---+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+
```

I have tried all outer joins, as well as a `crossJoin` which is the cartesian product between the two dfs, but didn't work. A brute solution would be to just duplicate the rows of df2 the number of times the corresponding id appears in df1 and then do a normal outer join, but I think there must be a way to get the desired result by using joins.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: the issue was that with crossJoin, you cannot specify on which column to do the join. its just a standard cartesian product. so the output was incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just join on the `id`:

```
df1.join(df2, 'id').show()
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| id|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  0| 1.5| 8.4| 9.1| 2.1| 3.4| 4.2|
|  0| 5.9| 1.3| 3.3| 2.1| 3.4| 4.2|
|  0| 3.2| 7.9| 4.2| 2.1| 3.4| 4.2|
|  0| 6.9| 2.2| 1.2| 2.1| 3.4| 4.2|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```